# Superagent 'request' object is being redefined as function?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, assert, superagent, should.js

I'm trying to put together a `supertest`-based integration test suite (run by Mocha) that pings our REST API and validates the response.

However, my test doesn't seem to be running as expected:

```
var assert = require('assert')
var should = require('should')
var request = require('superagent')

var WEBSERVICE_BASE = 'localhost:8080/our-application/'

describe('Authentication', function() {
  it('prevents user from logging in without credentials', function() {
    console.log('###')
    console.log('Starting with: ' + request)
    console.log('###')
    request.get(WEBSERVICE_BASE + 'auth', function(err, res) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err)
      if (err) {
        throw err
      }
      res.should.have.status(401)
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

What I see in the console:

```
Craigs-MBP:mocha-tests Craig$ ./run.sh


  Authentication
###
Starting with: function request(method, url) {
  // callback
  if ('function' == typeof url) {
    return new Request('GET', method).end(url);
  }

  // url first
  if (1 == arguments.length) {
    return new Request('GET', method);
  }

  return new Request(method, url);
}
###
    ✓ prevents user from logging in without credentials

    1 passing (12ms)
```

It seems `request` is being redefined as a function, instead of the `superagent` object?

The test should **not** pass, and at the very least the `console.log` printing the `err` parameter should be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, javascript is asynchronous. Superagent terminates the test before your callback is called unless you put the "done" parameter in the it method like so:

```
it('prevents user from logging in without credentials', function(done) {...
```

The test finished executing and mocha terminated before the callback ever gets called.

Comment: That was it! Thanks. Seems very scary that no error was reported, *and* the test passed?